# Is there a better way to add failed node back to postgres cluster?

Tags: postgresql, replication, restore, clustering

- There are 2 nodes in the cluster: node1(primary) and node2(replica).
- I will shutdown node1 and promote node2 as primary.
- I'll add the node1 back to the cluster (as a replica this time), so I am using the following procedure on failed node1:

---

```
systemctl stop postgresql-12
rm -rf /var/lib/pgsql/12/data/*
pg_basebackup -h node2 -D /var/lib/pgsql/12/data/ -U replicator -P -v  -R -X stream -C -S pgstandby1
systemctl start postgresql-12
```

Is there a better way? I don't like that I'm deleting everything from /var/lib/pgsql/12/data/, and it takes some time until restoring, especially when there's a lot of data.
What are your considerations gentleman?

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what `pg_rewind` was written for. It allows you to undo any transactions that have happened on `node1` after `node2` was promoted. It can be seen as a fast version of `pg_basebackup` in this case.

There is no guarantee that `pg_rewind` will succeed. It depends on whether you have all the WAL since the last common checkpoint of `node1` and `node2`. If there is not enough, you have to resort to `pg_basebackup`.

You can make sure that old WAL is kept around for a while by setting `wal_keep_size` (`wal_keep_segments` in older releases) appropriately.

Comment: Nice. So it seems to work. First I need to stop the postgres service. Then execute "/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_rewind --target-pgdata=/var/lib/pgsql/12/data/ --source-server="port=5432 host=node1 password=secretpass". It brings the data, but also it's making the server as master, so I have a split brain situation here. Not really sure how to solve it.

Comment: It does not make the server a master server, it turns it into a backup. You have to configure recovery and set at least `primary_conninfo` before starting.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Does wal_keep_size play role as node2 is promoted here and there is no standby yet for node2. Is min_wal_size correct way to preserve?

Comment: @NirajNandane I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe How can we ensure that on promoted node, pg_wal directory should have minimal WAL segment preserved? For eg. I want to preserve lets say 1GB, then how to do this provided node is promoted and no other node joined to the promoted node. This is for PG 14.

Comment: @NirajNandane I still don't understand. What is "preserving WAL"? On which node? How do you join a promoted node? I think you should ask a new question and explain in detail what you mean.